# zscore v.s. minmax normalization, why their results look the same

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to normalize my time series with two different normalization method, minmax and zscore and compare the results. Here is my code:

```
def scale_raw_data_zscore(raw_data):
    scaled_zscore = pd.DataFrame()
    idx = 514844
    values = raw_data.loc[idx]['d_column'].values
    values = values.reshape((len(values), 1))
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler = scaler.fit(values)
    normalized = scaler.transform(values)
    normalized = normalized.reshape(normalized.shape[0])
    normalized = pd.DataFrame(normalized, index=raw_data.loc[idx].index, columns=raw_data.columns)
    scaled_zscore = scaled_zscore.append(normalized)
    return scaled_zscore

def scale_raw_data_minmax(raw_data):
    scaled_minmax = pd.DataFrame()
    idx = 514844
    values = raw_data.loc[idx]['d_column'].values
    values = values.reshape((len(values), 1))
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaler = scaler.fit(values)
    normalized = scaler.transform(values)
    normalized = normalized.reshape(normalized.shape[0])
    normalized = pd.DataFrame(normalized, index=raw_data.loc[idx].index, columns=raw_data.columns)
    scaled_minmax = scaled_minmax.append(normalized)
    return scaled_minmax

def plot_data(raw_data, scaled_zscore, scaled_minmax):
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    idx = 514844
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311) 
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312) 
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
    raw_data.loc[idx].plot(kind='line', x='date', y='d_column', ax=ax1, title='ID: ' + str(idx), legend=False, figsize=(20, 5))
    scaled_zscore.reset_index(drop=True).plot(kind='line', y='d_column', ax=ax2, title='zscore', color='green', legend=False, figsize=(20, 5))
    scaled_minmax.reset_index(drop=True).plot(kind='line', y='d_column', ax=ax3, title='minmax', color='red', legend=False, figsize=(20, 5))
    pyplot.show()

scaled_zscore = scale_raw_data_zscore(raw_data)
scaled_minmax = scale_raw_data_minmax(raw_data)
plot_data(raw_data, scaled_zscore, scaled_minmax)
```

I'm adding the plot of the results. Why the results of both scaling methods are exactly the same? And why they have a different pattern from the raw data?

[image]

Comment: please also put the code that calls these functions.

Comment: @EmmetB Any idea why the two approaches end up with the same results?

Comment: they are not exactly the same. zscore scaled data take negative values, but the minmax take only positive. The shapes should resemble each other.